# Why tableview numberOfRowsInSection is not updating after insertRows executed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using reverse tableView with `TableView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1)` and reverse `tableViewCell`,  and updating it with `insertRows` and `deleteRows` methods. `tableView` works fine if the insertion and deletion is done in the visible area of `tableView`. If the updating methods are not done in visible area it crashes.

```swift
func insertEntries(){
        if itemsToInsert.count == 0{
            return
        }
        let entry = itemsToInsert.first
        itemsToInsert.removeFirst()
        dataArray.append(entry!)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.bottom)

        tableView.endUpdates()
        insertEntries()
}
```

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
```

Error is :

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
>   (50) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section
>   before the update (47), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or
>   deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus
>   the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0
>   moved out).

Thank you

Comment: The code itself is valid and should work. plase provide information: where the "append and insert" func is being execuded. Also whetherer there are further places where the "dataArray" is being manipulated.

Comment: The error is very specific, as you can see it detects a wrong number of items after the update. (5 rows were added instead of just 1). check if you change the dataAray somewhere else

Comment: @PaulReznik "append and insert" are executed exactly like in the code. Where can i manipulate dataArray. Does it matter where did i manipulate if i update it before insertRow.

Comment: The code you posted can't generate that error. The code you posted only adds one row. But the error shows a difference of 5 rows and claims you only inserted 1 while deleting 1 also. So you need to show all of the relevant code that is updating your data model, inserting, deleting, and reloading rows.

Comment: The code calls itself recursively. For example, there are 5 entries to insert and it appends an entry to dataArray one by one recursively. '5 rows' is because of that

Comment: You need to show enough code for people to help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as it stands wouldn't really do multiple animations since all the animations are actually created at the same time.

Nevertheless, the code should work in theory. In practice though, there are strange things in the `UITableView` implementation that makes similar things hard to do and would be much easier with `UICollectionView` that doesn't have those problems.

Also note that you are appending an item but you are trying to insert the first row. That's obviously incorrect.

One way to fix your code is not to trigger the animation until the previous animation ends, which is probably what you really want to do:

```
func insertEntries(){
    guard !itemsToInsert.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    let entry = itemsToInsert.removeFirst()
    dataArray.append(entry)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: dataArray.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [weak self] in
        self?.insertEntries()
    }

    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)

    tableView.endUpdates()        
}
```

If you don't want to animate one row after the other, which could take considerable time with multiple items, I would simplify to:

```
func insertEntries(){
    guard !itemsToInsert.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    dataArray.append(contentsOf: itemsToInsert)
    let numItems = itemsToInsert.count
    itemsToInsert = []

    let addedRows = Array((dataArray.count - numItems) ..< dataArray.count)
        .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0 })

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: addedRows, with: .bottom)
    tableView.endUpdates()        
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to insert first row(which is the bottom row in reverse TableView), it works as I expected if the page is not scrolled.i pick the first solution to insert one row after the another. But the problem still exists. I have tried the same methods and TableView in another project and it works fine. Is it possible to fail in `cellForRowAt:` func which is quite large in my case because of its size and cell rendering time? Thanks again

Comment: @fatihm It seems you are changing `dataArray` somewhere else then.

Comment: i search for it in the first place but no. And if `dataArray ` changes somewhere else, it shouldn't work when updating visible area of tableview.

Comment: @fatihm it doesn't matter the table view is inverted. The inversion is only a visual detail, the rows and data should match each other.

Comment: @akaralar Actually it's not so simple. When you insert a row, only that cell is reloaded, therefore when your operations are not in sync, you will end up with a duplicate row.

Comment: @akaralar data and rows match if i insert to the `row = 0` with just a trick in the `cellForRowAt:` method -> `cellData = dataArray[dataArray.count-indexPath.row-1]`

Comment: @fatihm @sulthan What I tried to say was that you should make your data models so that they match how the tableview handles data, so that you won't have to do index manipulation and all. If you insert `row = 0` you should also insert data at `dataArray[0]`. If `row = 0` and `cellData = dataArray[dataArray.count-indexPath.row-1]` does the correct thing, I would argue that you should have `tableDataArray = dataArray.reversed()` and use `tableDataArray` for table view stuff

Comment: @fatihm don't get me wrong, of course this is not a requirement, but I find working with an array that mimics how tableview handles data to be easier and less error prone than calculating indexes myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform model updates between `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`, doing only the `tableView` updates there might lead to problems.

Also the index you are inserting the row at and the index of the inserted item do not match. You are appending to the end of your `dataArray` but inserting at `IndexPath(row: 0, section:0)`

Can you check if this solves your problem?

```swift
func insertEntries(){
        if itemsToInsert.count == 0{
            return
        }
        let entry = itemsToInsert.first
        itemsToInsert.removeFirst()

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        dataArray.insert(entry!, at: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.bottom)

        tableView.endUpdates()
        insertEntries()
}
```